# Is it okay to pass a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage object around on a delegate in C#?

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks, smtp, mailmessage

I have made a small SmtpSender class which handles the sending of an Smtp MailMessage object.  When the message has been sent or failed to send I raise a delegate that contains a 'response' object that has the original MailMessage that the user was trying to send along with a success/fail boolean and an error string.  The user can then resubmit the MailMessage object to the sender class to try again if they wish.

What I want to know is... if I raise a delegate that contains an object with unmanaged resources, do I need to then dispose the object in the current scope? If so will calling Dispose on it in the current scope kill the object that the delegate function receives? I am concerned about memory leaks in the long run here.

Any advice or help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Dave

```
public delegate void SmtpSenderSentEventHandler(object sender, SmtpSendResponse theResponse);

public class SmtpSendResponse : IDisposable
{
    #region Private Members

    private MailMessage _theMessage;
    private bool _isSuccess;
    private string _errorMessage;

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    public MailMessage TheMessage
    {
        get { return _theMessage; }
        set { _theMessage = value; }
    }

    public bool IsSuccess
    {
        get { return _isSuccess; }
        set { _isSuccess = value; }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { return _errorMessage; }
        set { _errorMessage = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public SmtpSendResponse(MailMessage theMessage, bool isSuccess)
        : this(theMessage, isSuccess, null)
    { }

    public SmtpSendResponse(MailMessage theMessage, bool isSuccess, string errorMessage)
    {
        _theMessage = theMessage;
        _isSuccess = isSuccess;
        _errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_theMessage != null)
        {
            _theMessage.Attachments.Dispose();
            _theMessage.Dispose();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Just be sure to dispose of it when you know you're done with it, the object exposes the `Dispose` method to destroy itself for you on demand. Generally if an object contains a disposable object then they are responsible for managing it, your class handles the disposal - so it's really down to when your class is finished with. Though I could see the argument for not passing such items around in this manner, as some might ask: what is responsible for the root object? As if you dispose in the handler, what about the next subscriber, if any? Good question.

Comment: FYI, to clarify the 'object with unmanaged resources' that I refer to is the MailMessage object.

Comment: To Mr. Disappointment.  The sender class has an event of type SmtpSenderSentEventHandler.  This gets raised to the subscriber with a SmtpSendResponse object.  The subscriber then has to test if success is true and if so, they then dispose it.  If success is false they might want to try a resend using the same MailMessage object.

Comment: This code doesn't do anything.  Without it, the client code would look almost the same, minus the problem of it having to figure out why it failed and when to dispose objects.  Try it.

Comment: It's not supposed to do anything.  It's just a holder object which represents the result of an Smtp send, it gets passed on a delegate for the subscriber to interrogate.  The subscriber is likely to be a form or something, and they'll just show the error to the user and offer them the ability to retry. If they want to retry then they need the MailMessage object to pass back into the sender class.  If it was successful at that point then they would dispose it.

Answer (score 2):

When you call dispose on an Object you say you're done with it and that it should go into a 'broken' state that can be cleaned up by the garbage collector. So once its disposed I wouldn't use it again. So only dispose it when you're done with it.

The last object to use/touch the class should dispose it. Don't dispose it early.

Comment: And when is too early, in this case? The thing is that subscribers of an event don't inherently know who else is subscribed to that event, and really, it's none of their business. If I commanded the paper boy to go back to the newsagents because he's delivered my paper, then what about my neighbours' paper? I think this is where the question really becomes more of a thought-worthy one than initially presumed.

Comment: Following the analogy if you say to the paperboy, 'go home' it should know if it has to deliver any more papers and if not it happily complies.
In the code, normally the MailMessage _theMessage knows to dispose on garbage collection when there are no more reference to it. So dispose of all delegates and don't keep a list of records on a shared (static) object.